# Creating a backbone view for a collection

Tags: backbone.js

How can I bind a backbone view to a collection rather than a model? Do I need to wrap the collection in a model?

e.g.

If I have a backbone model Client and a collection of these called Clients

```
Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        Name: ''
    }
});

Clients = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Client,
    url: 'Clients'
});
```

and a view

```
    var ClientListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($("#clients-template").html()),
        el: $('#clientlist'),

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');

            this.collection = new Clients();
        },

        render: function( event ){
            $(this.el).html(this.template({ this.collection.toJSON()));

            return this;
        }
    });
```

then I can't access each client element in the underscore template. However if I wrap the collection like this

```
$(this.el).html(this.template({ clients: this.collection.toJSON() }));
```

then I can. Is this the correct way to go about this? I would expect this to be a common scenario but I can't find any examples on it, am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need to pass the wrapped collection.

Addy Osmani is using similar approach in his [Backbone Fundamentals](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals) examples - see for example [this view](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals/blob/master/practicals/modular-mobile-app/app/views/photoList.js) and corresponding [template](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals/blob/master/practicals/modular-mobile-app/app/templates/photoview.html):

In the view:

```
$el.html( compiled_template( { results: collection.models } ) );
```

In the template:

```
<% _.each( results, function( item, i ){ %>
   ...
<% }); %>
```

Another alternative is to have a view that will create separate view for each model in the collection. Here is an example from [An Intro to Backbone.js: Part 3 – Binding a Collection to a View](http://liquidmedia.ca/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/):

> ```
> var DonutCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
>   initialize : function() {
>     this._donutViews = [];
>     this.collection.each(function(donut) {
>       that._donutViews.push(new UpdatingDonutView({
>         model : donut,
>         tagName : 'li'
>       }));
>     });
>   },
>
>   render : function() {
>     var that = this;
>     $(this.el).empty();
>
>     _(this._donutViews).each(function(dv) {
>       $(that.el).append(dv.render().el);
>     });
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: Do you need a `var that = this;` at the top of the initialize method in the last example?

Comment: @dubilla No, backbone sets the context to `this` for the proxied underscore methods.

Comment: Why is there an underscore character for `this._donutViews = [];` ?

Comment: @fortuneRice It's just a convention to represent private variables in JavaScript. Since JavaScript doesn't have an explicit way to define private members, this convention is pretty common to differentiate it from public members.

Comment: Wouldn't the 2nd one be ideal in most cases? All visual related functionality in render is utilised whereas the first one no?

Comment: The example link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [backbone collectionView](http://rotundasoftware.github.io/backbone.collectionView/).